# Restoring the Skype contact window

Tags: skype

If I close the Skype window, how do I get it back?

Clicking the Skype icon on the launcher just tries to create a new Skype instance.  The only way I can get it back is by killing it via the terminal and re-launching it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Skype requires the sni-qt:i386 package to be installed to integrate with the indicator area in Ubuntu 11.10.  To install this package, run the following from the commandline:

> sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386

Then kill and restart skype again.  After that, you should always have the icon in the panel and be able to get to it even after closing the window.

Comment: Wanted to confirm that even though I already had sni-qt installed, and I had the 64-bit version of Skype, the trick really is to install sni-qt:i386.  Worked like a charm.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the skype is running, there should be a skype icon :
[image: skype icon]

Comment: I don't get the icon there.  I'd take a screenshot but Skype keeps closing itself and then telling me that there's already an instance running!

Comment: @blackn1ght You can try to reset the skype's configuration by deleting the `~/.Skype` directory

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to allow Skype to create its own icon: roobinatube's answer here worked for me.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861843