# Alt-tab does not display all applications

Tags: 12.04, skype

So far I'm loving 12.04.  I have read about several Alt-Tab issues, but none that sound like the one I'm encountering.

When I have Skype running, I can't alt-tab back to it.

I can get back to it with the "window spread" navigation (Shift+Alt+Up), but that only works for non-minimized windows.  If Skype has been minimized, there is no way** to get back to it.

Is there a way to allow Skype to show up in the alt-tab menu?  Are there other applications that also don't show up?  Thanks!

** Actually, it is *possible* to get back to it by [enabling the Skype taskbar icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66957/restoring-the-skype-contact-window), but that doesn't solve the alt-tab issue.

Comment: I have this issue, too.  I noticed it with Chrome at first, but it can (and I've seen it) happen to other windows as well.

Comment: Unity is not designed not to display windows. That means this is a bug. Press Alt+Tab and enter "ubuntu-bug unity" to send a bug report on Launchpad.net, which is where those kinds of issues are handled.

Comment: @notfed I haven't noticed the issue with Chromium, but haven't tried Chrome.  Is that what you're using?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad Thanks.  I clicked Cancel on the bug report (ran it before alt-tabbing) and it froze.  Where are those kinds of issues handled? :)

Comment: @mwcz: I'm sorry... I meant Alt+F2! Bug reports are handled on Launchpad.net.

Comment: After one of the updates from the past week, the issue is resolved.  Thanks to whoever solved it!

Comment: With Skype the easiest work-around is to tell it to make an applet on the  action bar. (not sure that's what it's called.)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue too with Terminal so a built in program!  Thought that terminal just wasnt designed to show up but it appears fine after a reboot.

I had firefox open maximised and opened up a few terminal windows and none appeared in alt + tab.  I closed firefox and they were all in the background.

Rebooted and it is working OK now so seems random.